# git repo on S3, mounted on Ec2

Tags: git, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance, with an S3 mount. There is code in the S3 bucket that is usually modified on my development machine and then pushed to bitbucket. I can then pull this to the S3 bucket using the terminal on EC2 as you;d expect `git pull <remote> <branch>`

however, on occasion, the code is modified on s3 directly (eg using vi, or from jupyter / ipython notebook). When I try to `add`, `commit` and `push` there is v.strange behaviour.

In the `add` and `commit` cases, the terminal tells me that the action succeeds, but nothing actually changes (a `git status` quickly confirms this) ... what is going on?

essentially, I want:

- the repo to sit on bitbucket (tick)
- to be able to pull from bitbucket into the S3 bucket (tick - via an ec2 mount)
- to be able to *push* from s3 into the bitbucket - not working!

what's going on here?

Comment: Choose a server and let that be the source of truth (Bitbucket!). If you want a backup for your code in the AWS cloud, why not look into CodeCommit instead, and have a post commit hook in Bitbucket that syncs up to AWS? You shouldn't be editing in two places and pushing in two directions, that's madness.

Comment: true - but it still doesnt solve why i can't add and commit from teh ec terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok - the right way to do this is just to sync the repo from bitbucket onto the ec2 instance directly. No need to use S3 to have a clone of the repo as Robbie Averill says